# Document sent/delivered/opened status in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have seen that Facebook, Snapchat, WhatsApp, etc. tells me whether a message is sent, delivered, opened, etc.

I guess deciding whether it's sent, delivered, or opened depends on following:

- **Sent:** The user has clicked send message in the client, but the server doesn't know anything about it yet
- **Delivered:** The server has received/stored the message
- **Opened:** A boolean flag field changed when the recipient opens message

I think the server on insertion should set the status as "delivered", and if the server haven't stored the message in the database yet, the status should be shown as "sent" on the client.

How can I make this distinguishing in Meteor, telling the user exactly what is happening with the message he/she just sent?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the right approach. Let me rephrase your assumptions on the sent/delivered/opened states:

- **Sent:** The user has clicked send message in the client, *and* the server  has received/stored the message
- **Delivered:** The message has been sent to to recipient UI (so he could have seen the header). Basically, it means that the targeted user Id has subscribed to the data source containing the message.
- **Opened:** A boolean flag field changed when the recipient opened the message

Starting from there, you should be able to achieve this smoothly. Comment if you need more help, I'll edit the answer.